# Passing items from custom template to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce-connect

I have a scenario with Sitecore 9.2 where the client lists bio pages for personnel in a custom template, which has their bio info, related articles and content via lookup lists, etc. The client also maintains this information in Salesforce, and they currently manually transfer the information to Salesforce. They would like to automate this process.

I looked at the Sitecore Salesforce connector, but that seems to either be for transferring xDB contact data (the behavior connector) or media items (the content connector), not information from any template I choose. Am I looking at the docs correctly and that's the case, or are one or the other useful in the case I'm considering?

If neither of the Sitecore connectors are appropriate, has anyone done this kind of operation and could point me toward docs/blogs/etc that discusses setting it up? Right now our alternative is a CSV file generated once a month. The client doesn't need bidirectional pushing (just Sitecore to Salesforce is fine) and it doesn't have to be real-time, but that wouldn't be a bad feature.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we recommend having the single source of truth in Salesforce and pulling the data to Sitecore when needed. Since the data is already in Sitecore we’d create a Sitecore template that maps to the Sitecore personnel data items and use [S4S](https://www.fuseit.com/products/sitecore-salesforce-integration/) (or [G4S](https://www.fuseit.com/products/net-salesforce-integration/)) to push it to Salesforce instigated by a Sitecore change event or scheduled task. Various examples are [here](https://fuseit.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/S4S/pages/60817549/S4S+Code+Examples).

If you don’t want to use a FuseIT product you can use the [Salesforce .NET SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net.html)“